# image map in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, hyperlink, imagemap

I have a splashscreen that contains an image, and when you click it it closes, like:

```
<Canvas MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"> 
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/S3.ParametersUE.About;component/Resources/splash.jpg" />
        </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

Now, in the image there's also some text like 'http://www.site.com'

Is there a way in WPF to make this part clickable, so that when it's clicked, the web page opens in the browser; so basically the same behavior as an image map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any chance you can remove the text from the Image itself, and just position a Button styled as a HyperLink inside the Canvas? It would give you better control over the font, text, and link. For example, if the link ever changes you can just modify the XAML instead of recreating the image.

The only other alternative I can think of is tracking MouseMove and MouseClick events on the Canvas and if the mouse is within specific coordinates of the Canvas then change cursor and process the click event.

Comment: Thanks.. I worried that when the hyperlink it's not part of the image, if may not be positioned on the right location on different screens. For example, if I put a button on top of the hyperlink in the image (in design mode), and run the application on my second screen, the button has moved and is not over the hyperlink anymore...

Comment: @Ludwig Stuyck: If your background is set to Stretch then you can always set the position based on a percentage, and it should get positioned perfectly every time. You can either put it in a 3x3 grid which has the Columns/Row definitions set to a percentage, or you can create a converter that binds to the Canvas.Height/Width and returns a percentage of that for the Link's Canvas.Top/Left values